# nginx rewrite and Drupal

Tags: nginx, rewrite, regex

My web root is in /staging/ and I'm currently using this rewrite line:

```
 location / {
            # This is cool because no php is touched for static content
            try_files $uri @rewrite;
    }

    location @rewrite {
            # Some modules enforce no slash (/) at the end of the URL
            # Else this rewrite block wouldn't be needed (GlobalRedirect)
            rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;
    }
```

However, there are some links that are using URIs with "/staging/" so it gets rewritten twice:

```
/staging/staging/somefile.png
```

Can you help me fix my rewrite line so all URIs with the string "/staging/" should not be repeated? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't put "staging" in a subdirectory of the live site. It leads to problems like this and turns your nginx configuration into a mess. Use a subdomain instead.

Comment: I've already made the "/staging/" directory the live site but there are URLs that are still hard-coded and pointing to "/staging/" -- thought this can be handled temporarily by nginx while we fix the URLs individually (or possibly use a filter).

Answer (score 0):

I was doing the rewrite in the wrong location! Placed the rewrite code in this section instead:

```
location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
    rewrite ^/staging/(.*)$ /$1;
    expires 30d;
    add_header Pragma public;
}
```

Any request to `/staging/file.jpg` is now rewritten as `/file.jpg`